# Extracting content from webpage with infinite scrolling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract content from [this webpage](https://opensea.io/collection/treasure-for-loot?search%5BsortAscending%5D=true&search%5BsortBy%5D=PRICE&search%5Btoggles%5D%5B0%5D=BUY_NOW) with following script:

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"J:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

try:
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3
    url = driver.get("https://opensea.io/collection/treasure-for-loot?search[sortAscending]=true&search[sortBy]=PRICE&search[toggles][0]=BUY_NOW")

    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

What I'm searching for is Bag #*id* of all currently listed items ("Buy Now" filter option). [image]

But after the script is finished I'm only getting about third of all listed items for example 102 items even though I know there is 243 items listed. Is there any way how to get them all? Thank you.

Comment: I see no scraping in your code, only scrolling the page until the end is reached and then `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")`

Comment: You are right I renamed it to extracting content. I hope I'm more clear now.

Comment: OK, when you extracting the content, you said you are getting about 1/3 of the data. Is it the last 1/3 of the data presented on the page (as I guess)?

Comment: Actually it is the first 1/3 of the data not last third as I would expect as well.

Comment: what is SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME? how long time is it?

Comment: It waits 3 seconds before it scrolls down again. It can be lest for example 0.5 second. I dont think it matters much.

Comment: 3 seconds should be enough. Can you try increasing it to 7 seconds to make sure it's 100% enough?

Comment: I did and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: OK, try getting the content inside the loop, not after getting the bottom. You will have to remove the duplications of cause.

Comment: Actaully I thought of that and I tried that as well but I got 7 times the same result.

Comment: Sure, In this case you will get a lot of duplicates. But does this give you all the results, not only 1/3?

Comment: @Michal I still don't see the code where you are at all trying to get the _listed items_

Comment: @Prophet It is the same content over and over.

Comment: I know. I asked if you are finally getting all the content (with many duplicates) in this case or not?

Comment: Also you seem to driver.get at the start of each infinite scroll so are you trying to reset it? Shouldn't it be outside.